# Getting javascript text by RegEx C#

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, parsing

I have the html content with following value in javascript:

```
$('#hotel').val(9864);
var hotel_id = $('select#hotel option:selected').val();
$.ez( 'ezjscvincci::setHotelDetails', {arg1: hotel_id}, function( data )
{
    computeHotelAvailabilityLink();
});
```

now i want to get the 9864 ID out of those javascripts by Regex, could you suggest me an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as Robin's but with c#:

```
string value = Regex.Matches( inputString, @"\$\('#hotel'\)\.val\((\d+)\)", RegexOptions.None )[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked well, as Im also new to regex, could you suggest me how to get the number of 160 from this url ? https://reservas.hoteldirecto.es/2/front/index/hotel/160/ Thanks @Derek

Comment: Regex.Matches( inputString, @".+/(\d+)", RegexOptions.None )[0].Groups[1].Value;

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the id following the `hotel` part in this code snippet you can use something like:

```
\$\('#hotel'\).val\((\d+)\)
```

`\d+` is a shortcut for `[0-9]` and your result will be in the first capturing group: http://regex101.com/r/wS7qH7

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, could you please suggest me the idea if I wish to get the number 3999 in this URL ? http://www.vinccihoteles.com/busqueda/(idPartner)/VINCCI/(codigoHotel)/3999/(zona)/74986/(lang)/es/(idPrm)/MBVINCCI/(idONg)/P69/(idNom)/VincciHoteles/(idListaHoteles)/Y/(dia)/10/(mes)/4/(anio)/2014/(diaHasta)/11/(mesHasta)/4/(anioHasta)/2014/(habitaciones)/1/(irListaHoteles)/Y/(adultsRoom1)/2/(childrenRoom1)/0

Comment: This is a different question, please ask about that (after trying something yourself) in another post to get help from the community.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use this :

`Match match = Regex.Match(youString, @"val([0-9]*)");`

And then get the value :

`string value = match.Value;
int numValue = int.Parse(value);`

Comment: You also need to add escaped parenthesis to match the one from `val(...)`.